# Sort and remove duplicates based on column

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have a text file:

```
$ cat text
542,8,1,418,1
542,9,1,418,1
301,34,1,689070,1
542,9,1,418,1
199,7,1,419,10
```

I'd like to sort the file based on the first column and remove duplicates using `sort`, but things are not going as expected.

#### Approach 1

```
$ sort -t, -u -b -k1n text
542,8,1,418,1
542,9,1,418,1
199,7,1,419,10
301,34,1,689070,1
```

It is not sorting based on the first column.

#### Approach 2

```
$ sort -t, -u -b -k1n,1n text
199,7,1,419,10
301,34,1,689070,1
542,8,1,418,1
```

It removes the `542,9,1,418,1` line but I'd like to keep one copy.

It seems that the first approach removes duplicate but not sorts correctly, whereas the second one sorts right but removes more than I want. How should I get the correct result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you provide a `key` to `sort` the unique occurrences are looked for that particular field. Since the line `542,8,1,418,1` is displayed, `sort` sees the next two lines starting with `542` as duplicate and filters them out.

Your best bet would be to either sort all columns:

```
sort -t, -nk1,1 -nk2,2 -nk3,3 -nk4,4 -nk5,5 -u text
```

or

use `awk` to filter duplicate lines and pipe it to `sort`.

```
awk '!_[$0]++' text | sort -t, -nk1,1
```

Comment: `uniq` requires the input file to be sorted. Is it possible that the output of `sort` based on column 1 is not sorted based on all columns?

Comment: My guess is that if I can sort based on (1,2,3,4,5) using `-nk1,5`, then `uniq` should work, but for some encrypted reasons it doesn't work.

Comment: @Yang Hmm, you can also do `awk '!_[$0]++' text | sort -t, -nk1,1` to first filter duplicate lines and then pipe that to sort.

Comment: Thanks this does the trick. I have a remaining question why `-nk1,5` does not work? It is supposed to sort based on 1 first, then 2, etc, but the output is like approach 1.

Comment: @Yang That is not the right way to sort. You'll have to do `sort -t, -nk1,1 -nk2,2 -nk3,3 -nk4,4 -nk5,5 -u text` to sort for all the columns and then list `unique` lines from it.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting on a key, you must provide the end of the key as well, otherwise sort uses all following keys as well.

The following should work:

```
sort -t, -u -k1,1n text
```