# Sort duplicates by column

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed

Please consider the following example:

Two columns data:

```
ti piace o no la apple p181026 07348
ti piace o no la apple p181026 07349
ti piace o no la apple p181026 07345
```

where the `p[0-9]\s[0-9]` sequence is **tab** separated from the first column.

I would like to remove duplicates according only to the first column (alphabetic part of the line). I tried with:

```
sort  -u -t$'\t' -k1 -nr inputfile > out
```

and with

```
sort -t$'\t' -k1 -nr inputfile | uniq > out
```

with no success. I am afraid I am missing something abvious, but even by consulting other relevant [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847799/sort-and-remove-duplicates-based-on-column) on the matter I am still not able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience with me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to 'uniq' by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sort and bash:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 1,1 -u file
```

Output:

```
ti piace o no la apple  p181026 07348
```

Comment: It appears to work perfectly, thanks. Now I have clear how I messed up with the flags.

Answer (score 0):

Since your delimiter is NOT clear from samples, so I am going with `p[0-9]\s[0-9]` regex mentioned by you, could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/p[0-9]+ +[0-9]+]*/){a=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)} !array[a]++' Input_file
```

Comment: The file is tab separated.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting approach!

Comment: @Worice, I was going for simple approach :) but seems while pasting your samples tab is not there somehow so I thought to go by your 2nd hint of using regex then, cheers :)